# ApiController BadRequest(string message) method is not returning the custom message passed in parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webclient, bad-request

**On my console application I am making following `webClient` Request to upload the data.**

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Clear();
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    client.UploadStringCompleted += (data, exception) =>
    {
        if (exception.Error != null)
        {
            _log.Error("Error While Posting XYZSets data {0}", exception.Error);
        }
        client.Dispose();
    };
    var ApplicationUrl = string.Format("{0}/api/AAA/PostXYZSets", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationUrl"]);
    client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(ApplicationUrl), jsonData);
}
```

In my MVC application at some point I am returning the `IHttpActionResult` by following code.

```
[ServiceAuthentication]
public IHttpActionResult PostXYZSets(XYZSet[] xYZSets)
{
    return BadRequest("My Custom Error message"); 
}
```

But when `UploadStringCompleted` method receives exception, I nowhere find "My Custom Error message". it says (400) Bad Request.

Tell me what's wrong am i doing. thanks in advance.

Comment: Is BadRequest a custom class here? If yes, please share that code also.

Comment: Are you talking about ASP.NET Core MVC6? Or Web API 2?

Comment: The action does not look to be able to accept POST requests based on OP. Also how are you authenticating the request based on that attached attribute? Consider using `HttpClient`.

Comment: No, it is not a custom class. Web API 2.

Comment: Have you tried calling it using Fiddler, Postman or similar? If you debug your Web API controller, is the method called? Try adding         [HttpPost]
to your method.

Answer (score 0):

The response is in the string returned, not in the header. It's there. Just read the return string as you would read an Ok response.